# Merging/rendering multiple components in a single Route path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render multiple components on a single route. Is there a proper/more efficient way to do this in React Router v5? On my sample code below I wish to merge `addCategories` and `viewCategories` because they will be on the same route.

```
class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>               
        <div>
          <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
            <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to='/'>Asset Management</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
              <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/'>Home</Nav.Link>  
                <NavDropdown title="Manage" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                  <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to='/manage/category'>
                    Categories
                  </NavDropdown.Item>  
                </NavDropdown>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/manage/category'component={addCategories} />
          <Route path='/manage/category'component={viewCategories} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router lets you pass multiple children to a single `<Route/>` component. The following will work just fine (and is the [recommended way of constructing routes as of React Router 5.1](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/)):

```
class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Router>               
         <div>
            <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
              <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to='/'>Asset Management</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                      <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/'>Home</Nav.Link>  
                      <NavDropdown title="Manage" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                      <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to='/manage/category'>
                        Categories
                      </NavDropdown.Item>  
                      </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                  </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
                <Route path='/manage/category'>
                  <AddCategories />
                  <ViewCategories />
                </Route>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )}
}
```

Notice the fact that I changed your Route component (with the component prop) to just be a Route component with the route contents specified as children.

You must name your components in PascalCase for them to be picked up as React components - If you start with a lower case letter they will be inferred as HTML elements!

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed a better approach for my case and I'll take note of using PascalCase for my components.

Answer (score 1):

You could render a component that renders both `<AddCategories />` and `<ViewCategories />`.

e.g.

```
class Categories extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <AddCategories />
                <ViewCategories />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

And then in your route
`<Route path='/manage/category' component={Categories}/>`